# Select the columns in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

table1:

```
id  col1   col2   col3  col4  col5  col6
---------------------------------------------
1    1      2    null    null  null  null
2    null   1     1      1     null  null
```

table2:

```
id   contain
-------------
1    col1
1    col2
2    col2
2    col3
```

I want to select columns in table2 and convert them to string:

```
id   string
------------
1    1,2
2    1,1
```

How to realize it?

Comment: Do you have always 6 columns in `table1`? And what is your SQl Server version?

Comment: Yes ,table1 is always having 6 columns.

Comment: i have SQL Server 2019

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach to get the expected results is the following statement:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id int,
   col1 varchar(1),
   col2 varchar(1),
   col3 varchar(1),
   col4 varchar(1),
   col5 varchar(1),
   col6 varchar(1)
)
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id int, 
  contain varchar(4)
)
INSERT INTO table1 (id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
VALUES
   (1, '1',  '2', null, null, null, null),
   (2, null, '1', '1',  '1',  null, null)
INSERT INTO table2 (id, contain)
VALUES
   (1, 'col1'),
   (1, 'col2'),
   (2, 'col2'),
   (2, 'col3')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   t2.id, 
   STRING_AGG(j.colval, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY j.colname) AS [string]
FROM table2 t2
JOIN (
   SELECT t1.id, v.*
   FROM table1 t1
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
      ('col1', t1.col1),
      ('col2', t1.col2),
      ('col3', t1.col3),
      ('col4', t1.col4),
      ('col5', t1.col5),
      ('col6', t1.col6)
   ) v (colname, colval)
) j ON (t2.id = j.id) AND (t2.contain = j.colname)
GROUP BY t2.id
```

Result:

```
id  string
1   1,2
2   1,1
```